# Django handling pagination for dynamic order

Tags: django, pagination

I have done to query content and give as next_url, previous_url , etc. Problem is that query is based on dynamic sorting (just like Facebook newsfeed).

How can I handle for following scenario ?

User request page 1 and see article 10242. User haven’t request page 2 yet. Due to sorting algorithm, article 10242 will potentially moved to page 2. If so, when user request page 2, user will see duplicate post.

I can't simply delete duplicate post on app. It will be okay for duplicate issue but let say when user request page 1, article 10333 is in page 2 but when user request page 2, article 10333 moves to page 1. Is there any recommended mechanism for pagination to support dynamic sorting?

Comment: Do you have control over the sorting algorithm?

Comment: You could create a new model for people who have seen the article. This way you could .order_by('-has_seen') or something similar.

Comment: You could also have page 2 query .exclude() page 1 articles in the page 2 query.

Comment: @Aditya if user like a post, it will goes to top. I guess I don't have control. It is triggered by user.

Comment: @WilliamR.Marchand how will I handle for missing article also? (your both solution will solve for duplicate issue).

Comment: In what case would they be missing?

Comment: let say when user request page 1, article 10333 is in page 2 but when user request page 2, article 10333 moves to page 1. As a result , that article will be missing and user will never be able to view that.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1. Change the algorithm to hold a `dirty` parameter. Anytime someone likes it or changes are made, it becomes `dirty` and the sorting algorithm can be changed to factor it in. I used couple of search db's (elasticsearch and algolia) that allowed me to customize sorting order based on various parameters. Alongwith this change, you need a user state of what has been viewed and what can be viewed and use it as a filter.
   [Here](https://research.facebook.com/publications/tao-facebook-s-distributed-data-store-for-the-social-graph/) is a nice paper where facebook discusses some of its approaches.
2. A simpler approach would be to hold the information of what has been viewed by a user and when the user tries to fetch information filter/demote the article. Keeping per user state will take care of the issue where an article might be viewed by one person but not by another.
   I personally like nosql databases or something like redis/memcached for such state information

Comment: Thanks. Let me digest your suggestion.